# Can't display Mapbox tileset with layer control

Tags: leaflet, layers, mapbox, mbtiles

I think the problem is in the `mbURL`. Simplified script:

```
    osmUrl    = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    esriUrl   = 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServe\
r/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mtnbiker.d7jfhf8u.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibXRuYmlrZXIiLCJhIjoiNmI5ZmZjMzAyNzJhY2Q0N2ZlN2E1ZTdkZjBiM2I1MTUifQ.6R3ptz9ejWpxcdZetLLRqg';


var mbMap   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl),
    osmMap  = L.tileLayer(osmUrl),
    esriMap = L.tileLayer(esriUrl);

var map = L.map('map', {layers: [osmMap]})
           .setView([<%= @location.latitude %>, <%= @location.longitude %>], 17);

var baseLayers = {
  "OSM Street" : osmMap,
  "1908 LA [?]": mbMap,
  "Satellite"  : esriMap
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
```

You can see this in (in)action at [alpha site](https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/locations/26) and then click on stack on the right and select 1908 LA. No errors, but no display. I can display the tiles—click on [Map on the nav bar](https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/map), it's the same map I want to display. Something wrong in the syntax of `mbURL`, but I've looked searched and tried many alternatives. (The lat and long are Rails calls to a PostgreSQL database and they work, because they also display the marker. The ? mark in 1908 LA is to suggest the user that there may be a problem.)

Code is at https://git.heroku.com/secure-shore-68966.git. 
Tileset is at https://www.mapbox.com/studio/tilesets/mtnbiker.d7jfhf8u/.

Answer (score 1):

A `L.TileLayer` expects a **url template for tiled images**. What [you're feeding it](https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mtnbiker.d7jfhf8u.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibXRuYmlrZXIiLCJhIjoiNmI5ZmZjMzAyNzJhY2Q0N2ZlN2E1ZTdkZjBiM2I1MTUifQ.6R3ptz9ejWpxcdZetLLRqg) is a [TileJSON metadata **description** for the tileset](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-tilejson-metadata).

Look at the metadata manually, find the tile URL template, create a `L.TileLayer` with it:

```
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mtnbiker.d7jfhf8u/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibXRuYmlrZXIiLCJhIjoiNmI5ZmZjMzAyNzJhY2Q0N2ZlN2E1ZTdkZjBiM2I1MTUifQ.6R3ptz9ejWpxcdZetLLRqg").addTo(map);
```

See a [working example](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/jagi/edit?html,output).

Comment: Thank you. I see how that creates a single layer. But how do I make it one of the selectable layers?

I admit to being confused by the various syntaxes possible with Mapbox/Leaflet.

I had successfully displayed the 1908 LA map as a baselayer on https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/map

Comment: to make it as selectable layer, set your `mbUrl` variable as the string provided here. It should have the `{s}, {z}/{x}/{y}` parameters as the `osmUrl` variable does.